# Why component in the vue-router routes makes no difference

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vue-router

I have an `App` component and it renders fine. It's basically a component comprising two components.

```
App (Vue component):
    1. Navigation // a menu bar with menu items 
                  //like <router-link to="/">Home</router-link> 
                  //like <router-link to="/contact">Contact</router-link> 
    2. Library    // a component listing books.
```

I want to add another component `Contact` which I tried adding using vue-router, so I use the above navigation component. However, the routes don't seem to affect anything at all. What am I doing wrong?

My main.js file

```js
const Contact = {
  template: '<div>Contact Us</div>'
}

const routes = [
    { 
        path: '/', 
        component: App        // any change here also does not make any difference!!!
    },
    {
        path: '/contact',
        component: Contact,   // this or any component doesnt make any difference!!!
    }
];

const router = new VueRouter({
    routes,
});

new Vue({
  render: h => h(App),
  router,
}).$mount('#app')
```

Comment: could you  make a codepen like [this](https://codepen.io/koderdojo/details/rwQvbN) in order to debug it

Comment: The component will be injected into your `<router-view>`. It sounds like you don't have a `<router-view>`, so the router doesn't have anywhere to put the component. Change the `component: App` part to be the component you want to inject and try putting `<router-view>` inside your `App` template. You can move it elsewhere later once it's rendering the desired components.

Comment: I will write the answer in detail a bit later. But before answering I'll myself learn more.